# "Error: JsonRpcProvider failed to detect network - Deploying Contract with ethers.js and Ganache"

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js, ganache

I'm trying to deploy a contract using the ethers.js library and Ganache, following the course by Patrick Collins, but I'm encountering an issue with the JsonRpcProvider. I've followed the provided code and set up my environment variables, but I keep getting an error. Here are the details:

## deploy.js

```
const ethers = require("ethers")
// const solc = require("solc")
const fs = require("fs-extra")
require("dotenv").config()

async function main() {
    // First, compile this!
    // And make sure to have your ganache network up!
    // The old way can be seen below:
    // let provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL)
    // On ether 6 and above, you should use like this
    let provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL)
    // let provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL)
    let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider)
    // const encryptedJson = fs.readFileSync("./.encryptedKey.json", "utf8");
    // let wallet = new ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJsonSync(
    //   encryptedJson,
    //   process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD
    // );
    // wallet = wallet.connect(provider);
    const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8")
    const binary = fs.readFileSync(
        "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
        "utf8"
    )
    const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet)
    console.log("Deploying, please wait...")
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy()
    // const contract = await contractFactory.deploy({ gasPrice: 100000000000 })
    const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1)
    console.log(`Contract deployed to ${contract.address}`)
    // console.log("Here is the transaction:")
    // console.log(contract.deployTransaction)
    // console.log("Here is the receipt:")
    // console.log(deploymentReceipt)
    // const nonce = await wallet.getTransactionCount()
    // tx = {
    //   nonce: nonce,
    //   gasPrice: 100000000000,
    //   gasLimit: 1000000,
    //   to: null,
    //   value: 0,
    //   data: "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",
    //   chainId: 1337,

    // Additionally, there is a v,r,and s variable that ethers handles for us.
    // This is the signature of the transaction.
    // There is a lot of math going on with those values, but that's how it's gaurenteed that the transaction is signed!
    // https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/what-does-v-r-s-in-eth-gettransactionbyhash-mean


    // }
    // There is also a v, r, and s component of the transaction that Ethers will handle for us.
    // It's these three components that make up the cryptographic signature.
    // We won't go into this, because it's a lot of math.

    // console.log("Let's deploy another! Please wait...")
    // let resp = await wallet.signTransaction(tx)
    // const sentTxResponse = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
    // console.log(resp)

    let currentFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrieve()
    console.log(`Current Favorite Number: ${currentFavoriteNumber}`)
    console.log("Updating favorite number...")
    let transactionResponse = await contract.store(7)
    let transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait()
    currentFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrieve()
    console.log(`New Favorite Number: ${currentFavoriteNumber}`)
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })

// synchronous [solidity]
// asynchronous [javascript]

// cooking
// Synchronous
// 1. Put popcorn in microwave -> Promise
// 2. Wait for popcorn to finish
// 3. Pour drinks for everyone

// Asynchronous
// 1. Put popcorn in the mircrowave
// 2. Pour drinks for everyone
// 3. Wait for popcorn to finish

// Promise
// Pending
// Fulfilled
// Rejected
```

## Error:

```
Error: missing revert data (action="estimateGas", data=null, reason=null, transaction={ "data": "<transaction_data>", "from": "<sender_address>", "to": null }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.7.1)
    at makeError (path/to/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:125:21)
    at getBuiltinCallException (path/to/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/abi-coder.js:104:37)
    at AbiCoder.getBuiltinCallException (path/to/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/abi-coder.js:201:16)
    at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (path/to/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:599:43)
    at path/to/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:268:45
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  action: 'estimateGas',
  data: null,
  reason: null,
  transaction: {
    to: null,
    data: '<transaction_data>',
    from: '<sender_address>'
  },
  invocation: null,
  revert: null,
  info: {
    error: {
      message: 'VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode',
      stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n' +
        '    at exactimate (...)',
      code: -32000,
      name: 'RuntimeError',
      data: [Object]
    },
    payload: {
      method: 'eth_estimateGas',
      params: [Array],
      id: 4,
      jsonrpc: '2.0'
    }
  }
}
```

## SimpleStorage.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    // uint256[] public anArray;
    People[] public people;

    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

I attempted to address the issue by altering the server hostname to "vEthernet (WSL)" since I'm utilizing VSCode connected to WSL. Despite this adjustment, the error remains unresolved.

Comment: Does the account at `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY` has any ETH to deploy this contract?

Comment: yes. it does have.

Comment: Can you downgrade your `ethers.js` library to `5.6.1` (instead of `6.7.1` you are using now) and see if thats fine?

Comment: It shows error as : TypeError: ethers.JsonRpcProvider is not a constructor
    at main (/home/aadityasahu/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:12:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aadityasahu/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:71:1)

Comment: {
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ethers": "5.6.1",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "ganache": "^7.9.1",
    "solc": "^0.8.21"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "yarn solcjs --bin --abi --include-path node_modules/ --base-path . -o . SimpleStorage.sol"
  }
}
my package.json

Comment: Get it back to the original v6. `JsonRpcProvider` is not available in v5.

Comment: Can you share your solidity code as well?

Comment: I have updated the question adding the solidity code.

Comment: Can you verify if your variables at `process.env.*` has valid value in your deploy script??

Comment: Yes. Those are correct. One thing more. Note that when I start ganache server from terminal, without using gui, this error is not showing, but there are still some errors showing in the solidity part. However, using gui, I am not able to do so.

Comment: Can you show the solidity errors?

Comment: Current Favorite Number: 0
Updating favorite number...
Error: could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32000, "message": "the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 2 tx has nonce of: 1", "stack": "Error: the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 2 tx has nonce of: 1\n    at TransactionPool.prepareTransaction (/home/aadityasahu/hh-fcc/ethers-simple-storage/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:188489)" }, payload={ "id": 18, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_sendRawTransaction", "params": [ "***" ] }, code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.7.1)

Comment: can you share the whole logs from the terminal where you are running your deploy script?

Comment: For the nonce error, if you are using metamask, try clearing the activity and nonce data. Go to Settings, Advanced, Clear activity tab data.

Answer (score 0):

In ethers 6, try to change:

```
const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1)
```

to:

```
await contract.waitForDeployment(1)
```